# Android BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC not working

Tags: android, batterymanager

I have a `broadcastreceiver` that receives the event `android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` correctly.
Then I use this code to detect if the device has been connected to the wall `socket (AC)`, to a `USB` or to a Wireless charging:

```
  IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
  Intent batteryStatus = Contexto.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
  int chargePlug = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
  boolean bUsb = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
  boolean bAC = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
  boolean bWireless = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS;
```

It works in one device perfectly. But in another device it always says it is just in `USB` charging even when plugged to the wall. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: Is Working device below 3.1 and Not working device above 3.1?

Comment: Both are Android 4.x